# Assume $\lambda_\min(A_kA_k^{\rm T})>\varepsilon$ and show that $A_k^{\rm T}(A_kA_k^{\rm T})^{-1}$ is bounded

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-rank

For all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, let $A_k\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, where $n\leq m$, and assume that there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $\lambda_\min(A_kA_k^{\rm T})>\varepsilon$, where $\lambda_\min$ denotes the minimum eigenvalue of a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix. Can we show that $A_k^{\rm T}(A_kA_k^{\rm T})^{-1}$ is bounded?

For the case where $n=m$, I can see that $A_k^{\rm T}(A_kA_k^{\rm T})^{-1}$ is bounded. My question is about the case where $n<m$. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Note that $A_k^T(A_kA_k^T)^{-1}$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $A_k$.  It follows that we have 
$$
\max_{\|x\| = 1} \|A_k^T(A_kA_k^T)^{-1}x\| = \left[ \min_{\|x\| = 1} \|A_k x\| \right]^{-1}.
$$
I'm having trouble proving this result directly, but with this we can conclude that $\|A_k(A_kA_k^T)^{-1}\| \leq \epsilon^{-1/2}$, where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the spectral norm.

Comment: The singular values of the pseudo inverse are just ${1 \over \epsilon} >{1 \over \sigma_n} \ge \cdots \ge {1 \over \sigma_1} \ge 0 =\cdots = 0$, hence the norm is bounded.

Comment: @copper.hat I guess I was trying to find a proof that avoids appealing to pseudoinverses or singular-value decomposition, but in retrospect there's no real advantage to doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A= U \Sigma V^T$ where $\Sigma$ has the same form as $A$. Then
$A^T (A A^T)^{-1} = V \Sigma^T (\Sigma \Sigma^T)^{-1}U^T$.

We have $\Sigma^T (\Sigma \Sigma^T)^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} \operatorname{diag}({1 \over \sigma_1},\cdots, {1 \over \sigma_n}) \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Hence $\|A^T (A A^T)^{-1}\| = {1 \over \sigma_n} < { 1 \over \sqrt{\epsilon}} $.

Note that by assumption $\lambda_\min (A A^T) = \sigma_n^2 > \epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks. How can you see the last inequality?

Comment: The ($l_2$) norm of a matrix $A$ is its largest singular value. The largest singular value above is ${1 \over \sigma_n}$.

Comment: @Yasi: I was missing a square root.

Comment: Thanks, looks perfect.